# What is the probability that sum of two last digits of three digit number is less than 6?

Tags: probability

> What is the probability that sum of two last digits of three digit number is less than 6?

There are 900 three digit numbers and 30 ways we can add numbers from set $ {0,1,2,3,4,5}$ so that sum is less than six. $P=1/30$

Comment: What do you mean by two sum?

Comment: sorry, sum of two

Comment: Do you mean "there are $30$ ways to choose an ordered pair of digits that sum to $≤5$"?  That seems too high...

Comment: It is not true that "there are ... 30 ways we can add numbers from set 0,1,2,3,4,5 so that sum is less than six".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you counting the number of ways to add numbers from 0 to 5?

What you need to consider is the number of ways to add two digits and get less than 6.
If the first digit is 0, you have 6 options for the second digit (0,1,2,3,4,5).
If the first digit is 1, you have 5 options left (0,1,2,3,4) and so on, so the number of ways to add two digits and get less than 6 is

$$ 6+5+4+3+2+1 = 21. $$

So there are 21 ways for the last two digits to add up to something less than 6. Since the first digit of your 3 digit number doesn't matter, you have these 21 options 9 times. So the number of 3 digit numbers whose last two digits add up to less than 6 is

$$ 21 \cdot 9 = 189, $$

so the probability you are looking for is

$$ \frac{189}{900} = \frac{9\cdot 21}{9\cdot 100} = 21\%. $$

Comment: If the first digit is 0 we have six options (without 6)

Comment: *Less* than $6$.

Comment: Thank you to @1qwertyyy and Deepak for the correction, I edited the post

Answer (score 2):

The first digit is clearly unimportant, so we only need to find the probability that two randomly chosen numbers from $\{0, 1, \cdots, 9\}$ (with repetition allowed) is less than $6$.

The number of ways for two numbers to add to $n$ is $n+1$ (taking $(0,n), (1, n-1), \cdots, (n,0)$). So we sum this over $n = 0$ to $5$, to get $1+2+\cdots+6 = 21$.

Hence the probability is $\frac{21}{100}$.